# Installation of github on a windows SERVER

Tags: github

I see on github for windows it's for windows 7 and 8.
can you install it on windows server 2008 r2?
i have a fire walled server that is for our .net code as our team foundation server so I was going to use the same server to host our source control for cocoa/mac applications we have...

Comment: To be clear, GitHub for Windows is a Git *client*, not a Git server. It would typically be installed on developers' workstations. If you're looking for a Git server to host yourself you could pay for [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/), or use any one of a [number](https://www.gitlab.com/) of [open-source](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Gitweb) and/or [free](https://gitorious.org/) [options](http://bonobogitserver.com/).

Comment: And, in fact, [recent versions of TFS can be used as a backend for standard Git clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server#Git).

Answer (score 5):

If you are after a Git *server* (as in able to host git repos), you can consider, on Windows, the [Bonobo Git server](http://bonobogitserver.com/).

It knows how to interface with IIS, and is compatible with various Windows releases, including  windows server 2008 r2.